# Type checking with generics and raw types?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a class

```
class SomeViewController<T: SomeViewModel>: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource { ... }
```

And another class:

```
class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {
    private weak var someVC: UIViewController?
    ...
    func someFunc() {
        if someVC is SomeViewController { ... } // attempt 1
        // or
        if let vc = someVC as? SomeViewController { ... } // attempt 1
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I need to see if `someVC` is a `SomeViewController` so that I can access an instance variable that has nothing to do with the generic type. However, when doing a check via either `attempt 1` or `attempt 2`, the check always fails and my inner code never executes. How do I see if it is of a type, but not specific generic type e.g. I don't have to put the type of `SomeViewModel`?

EDIT: Added more code for clarity.

Comment: Can you post your code? 
the code of the second view controller

Comment: Added more. Can't post much code due to "limitations".

Comment: When you are debugging, are you able to see the type of `someVC`? Is that `SomeViewController` itself?

Comment: You need to provide code that  how you assign `someVC` variable. I can see it is `private`  so how you define the value of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because Swift wants to know the type of the generic. If you just want to access a property without dealing with the generic, you can extract that to a protocol.

```
protocol SomethingThatHasFoo {
  var foo: String { get }
}

class SomeViewController<T>: UIViewController, SomethingThatHasFoo {
  let foo = "foo"
}

class AnotherViewController {
  private weak var someVC: UIViewController?

  func someFunc() {
    if let vc = someVC as? SomethingThatHasFoo {
      print(vc.foo)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this as this seems the cleanest and most flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works:

```
class SomeViewModel{}

class A: SomeViewModel{}

class SomeViewController<T: SomeViewModel> : UIViewController{}

class AnotherViewController {

  private weak var someVC: UIViewController?

  init(vc: SomeViewController<A>) {
      someVC = vc
  }

  func someFunc() {
      if someVC is SomeViewController<A> {
          print("\(String(describing: someVC))")
      }
      if let vc = someVC as? SomeViewController<A> {
          print("\(vc)")
      }
}
```

Then you have to initialize it like this:

```
    let someVC = SomeViewController<A>()
    let anotherVC = AnotherViewController.init(vc: someVC)
    anotherVC.someFunc()
```

Hope that answered your question

Comment: While a good proof of concept, I can't have a custom initializer for it like you have. Thank you though!

Comment: You are welcome!, you may want to give it a vote :D